# What's the scope of a private top-level class with access qualifier set to the same package where the class is defined in Scala?

Tags: scala, scope

I have read [this](http://www.jesperdj.com/2016/01/08/scala-access-modifiers-and-qualifiers-in-detail/) article to better understand Scala scoping rules.

Everything seemed clear until I ran into some code on GitHub that was like this:

```
package x.y.z

private[z] class ExampleClass {
   // class body
}
```

As you can see, we have a private top-level class, and there's an access qualifier to modify the scope of that class, but it's set to the very same package where the class is defined. If the access qualifier was set to an enclosing scope (e.g. package y) I would perfectly get it, but like this I can't understand the difference with simply declaring the class as private:

```
package x.y.z

private class ExampleClass {
   // class body    
}
```

So what is the difference between the two snippets posted above?

**NOTE:** I don't know if it's of any relevance, but in the same file a companion object for the class was defined and simply declared as private (with no access qualifiers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you provided both modifiers have the same effect. Difference would be more apparent if you had an enclosing class/object.

Compiles:

```
package x.y.z

object OuterExampleClass {
  private[z] class ExampleClass()
}

object AnotherObject {
  val ec = new OuterExampleClass.ExampleClass()
}
```

Fails to compile:

```
package x.y.z

object OuterExampleClass {
  private class ExampleClass() // no [z] !!!
}

object AnotherObject {
  val ec = new OuterExampleClass.ExampleClass() // error
}
```

with message:

> class ExampleClass in object OuterExampleClass cannot be accessed in
>   object x.y.z.OuterExampleClass